Why does my Firefox extension not trigger a keyboard shortcut?
I'm using a Firefox CSS theme that basically removed the picture-in-picture option when watching videos. On this website I'm watching videos in, I would like to have the option again via an extension. Now on Firefox, when you press the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + ] it makes the video pop out. I want to make an extension that when clicked triggers the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + ] when its icon is pressed.
Here is the code for my attempt at making this extension:
background.js
    browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
      browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "triggerKeyCombo"});
      });
    });

content.js
    function triggerKeyCombo() {
      const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        code: 'BracketRight',
        keyCode: 221, // keyCode for ]
        ctrlKey: true,
        shiftKey: true,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      });
      document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
      if (message.action === "triggerKeyCombo") {
        triggerKeyCombo();
      }
    });

manifest.json
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "Trigger Key Combo",
      "version": "1.0",
      "description": "Triggers Ctrl + Shift + ] when the extension icon is clicked.",
      "icons": {
        "48": "icons/border-48.png"
      },
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
          "48": "icons/border-48.png"
        },
        "default_area": "navbar",
        "default_title": "Trigger Key Combo"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
      ],
      "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }]
    }

However, the extension when pressed does not trigger the shortcut...
Any ideas?
I expected to see it trigger the shortcut, just like clicking Ctrl + V, etc. I made sure to include all 3 files (with their file extensions) in the same folder along with an icon folder inside. What happened was that the video did not pop out, I don't know if it even pressed the shortcut in the first place because I don't know of any keylogging website. Any ideas?
